# Tricky Lebesgue problem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

There is this one Lebesgue problem I have trouble solving, and it goes:

**Problem:** For every positive integer $n$, let $f_n:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable. Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that for every $\epsilon > 0$, we have: $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} m^*(\{x\in[0,1]: |f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\})=0$$

Prove that $f$ is measurable.

So far I have some sketch of the solution but I am not sure if it is correct but it goes like this:

**My attempt:** First we consider some smaller problem where we define some $a_1, a_2, a_3, ...  \in (0, \infty)$ and $a_1+a_2+a_3+... <\infty$ and $E_1, E_2, E_3,... $ are subsets of $\mathbb{R} $ such that $m^* (E_k)<a_k$, then we have $$m^*(\bigcap_{K=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=K}^\infty E_n) = 0 $$ This part is easy to show. the next part is using this small result to apply to my question, and we have:

First we let $a_K = \frac{1}{2^K}$, then $\sum_{K=1}^\infty a_K=1<\infty.$ Now according to the definition of the limit we have $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2^K}>0$ there exists some $n_K$ such that $m^*(\{x\in[0,1]: |f_{n_K}(x)-f(x)|>\frac{1}{2^K}\})<\frac{1}{2^K}$. Let us define then that $$E_K = \{x\in[0,1]: |f_{n_K}(x)-f(x)|>\frac{1}{2^K}\}$$
Now if we let $S = \bigcap_{K=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=K}^\infty E_n$, then we know that $m^*(S)=0$ hence $S$ is measurable. For $x\in [0,1]\setminus S = \bigcup_{K=1}^\infty \bigcap_{j=K}^\infty([0,1]\setminus E_j)$ and this implies that there exists $K\in \mathbb{N},  \forall j\ge K$, and $x \notin E_j$. So there exists some $K\in \mathbb{N}, \forall j\ge K,$ $$|f_{n_j}(x)-f(x)|\le\frac{1}{2^K}$$ which further implies that:

$$\lim \limits_{j \to \infty} f_{n_j}(x)=f(x)$$
Since $m(S)=0$, we have $\lim \limits_{j \to \infty} f_{n_j}(x)=f(x)$ almost everywhere on $[0,1]$. Since $f_{n_j}$ are measurable hence $f$ is measurable.

Is this correct? Im not entirely sure if this is correct, can anyone give me some feedbacks to my attempt. If this approach is wrong, can anyone gimme an outline of the method to do this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not go through all the details of your answer but I believe this is equivalent to the following.

The set of points $x$ such that $f_{n}(x)$ does **not** simply converge to $f(x)$ can be written as: $\Delta = \cup_{k=1}^{+\infty}\cap_{N=1}^{+\infty}\cup_{n \geq N}\{x; |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|>\frac{1}{k}\}$ where using our hypothesis of "convergence in outer measure" we can show that $\mu^{*}(\Delta)=0$ (by subadditivity of the outer measure). Thus $(f_{n})$ converges to $f$ a.e. Since the Lebesgue measure is complete this allows us to conclude.